# ASP.NET 3.0 - не удается установить EF из nuget

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor

Пытаюсь создать проект в VS Community 2019 (16.3.2) с использованием Blazor. Есть необходимость работать с БД MS SQL. При попытке установки пакета из nuget Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer вылезают постоянно ошибки о не поддерживаемых пакетах:

```
Ошибка  NU1202  Пакет System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.3.0 несовместим с netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Пакет System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.3.0 поддерживает:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0) C:\Projects\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor.csproj  1

Ошибка  NU1202  Пакет Microsoft.Win32.Registry 4.5.0 несовместим с netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Пакет Microsoft.Win32.Registry 4.5.0 не поддерживает какие-либо целевые платформы. C:\Projects\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor.csproj  1

Ошибка  NU1202  Пакет System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.3.0 несовместим с netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Пакет System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.3.0 поддерживает:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0) C:\Projects\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor.csproj  1

Ошибка  NU1202  Пакет System.Collections.Specialized 4.3.0 несовместим с netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Пакет System.Collections.Specialized 4.3.0 поддерживает:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0) C:\Projects\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor.csproj  1

Ошибка  NU1202  Пакет System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 несовместим с netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Пакет System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 поддерживает:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0) C:\Projects\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor.csproj  1   

Ошибка  NU1202  Пакет System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.5.0 несовместим с netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0). Пакет System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.5.0 поддерживает:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0) C:\Projects\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor\PCAccounting_Blazor.csproj  1
```

Куда копать, что обновлять - подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте шаблон Server-Side Blazor вместо Blazor Wasm.
Также обновите Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer до версии 3.0.0